# Limit requests only up to Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I created a project in which an Angular application is served by Spring Boot.

I want to hit localhost:8090/login and render the LoginComponent

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AuthGaurdService } from './auth-gaurd.service';


const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'user', component: UserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGaurdService] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {path : '', component : LoginComponent}

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

but instead of rendering the frontend, it is calling the backend, I added the below code just for test otherwise all I have to do is to render the LoginComponent and I can see "index" text on the webbrowser on hitting localhost:8090/login

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage()
        throws Exception
    {
        return "index";
    }
```

Is there any way to limit it to render the LoginComponent ?

Comment: How are they running on the same port? Is springboot serving the angular pages too?

Comment: you have to add the angular project in springboot project as dependency and add plugin to serve the purpose